# Property Is Not Updating Registry Value Advanced Installer

Tags: advanced-installer

I want to do something simple. Update a Registry Value with Advanced Installer.

```
The steps I took
1. Create a Property "LWL_KEY_2"
2. Create a Dialog with an Edit Box and set the Property name to "LWL_KEY_2"
3. Bind the Property Name to The Registry Key
```

The log shows the property gets the user input

```
SI (c) (04:28) [14:48:11:280]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying LWL_KEY_1 property. Its current value is 'nick1'. Its new value: 'abc123'.
MSI (c) (04:28) [14:48:23:748]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying LWL_KEY_2 property. Its current value is 'nick2'. Its new value: 'xyz456'.
Action ended 14:48:23: NewSeqDialog. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (04:88) [14:48:23:865]: Doing action: ExitDialog
Action 14:48:23: ExitDialog. 
Action start 14:48:23: ExitDialog.
```

The end result is the Registry Key is created but has no value. 
(If I set a default value that value gets populated in the registry)

Screenshots attached.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the dialog you use to set the registry property is executed/displayed after the WriteRegistryValues action is executed. This way the registry value is written before the user can input the registry value on your dialog.

To correct this bad design you should add your dialog, in Dialogs view of your advanced installer setup project, anywhere before the ProgressDlg dialog.

Comment: This could be my problem. Thank you! How to change the dialog order?

Comment: not sure how to do this, but you can try to delete an add the dialog again after PrepareDlg in the dialogs chain; also, instead of adding your dialog as a dialog in 
 sequence you may want to add it as a regular chained dialog - i.e. using the New Dialog option